# Multiple errors on cocos2d-x android project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I had problems with eclipse, so I have removed it, and installed the last version of it, but now when I run `cocos run -p android -j 4` I have this error:

```
E/Trace(625): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/Posix(29680): [CDS]Libcore_io_Posix-throwErrnoException, functionName: access; errno: No such file or directory
A/libc(678): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 692 (Thread-75)
```

I used in my project plugin-x Android IAP, Parse notification.

I developed with cocos2d-x V3.0 on The MAC.

stack-trace:

```
Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/IdeaTab_A1000-F/A1000F:4.1.2/JZO54K/A1000F_A412_01_83_130907_ROW:user/release-keys'
pid: 4045, tid: 4059, name: Thread-5082  >>> com.XXXXX.XXXXX <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
Stack frame #00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
Stack frame #01  pc 008b841c  /data/data/com.XXXXX.XXXXXXX/lib/libcocos2dcpp.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit+288): Routine ??
??:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, i forget to add this line `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \` to `jni/Android.mk` file. i was very stupid!